# How to stop Node.js command window from opening in VS 2017

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2017

I am having a problem with VS 2017 Ver. 15.9.6.  Every time I open a project, doesn't matter what it is MVC, Console, even Classic ASP, about 6 or 7 Node.js command windows pop open. A couple of them have information on them but most of them are blank. Can anyone help me, tell me how to stop the window from opening. There are a real pain.

Comment: Any specific reason you're using VS 2017 for Node.js project?

Comment: That's just it I am not using node for anything.  The command window just pop up anytime I open a VS project and I have no idea why.  The directory in the top shows it is originating in C:\program files(x86)\Microsoft visual studio\2017\community\msbuild\microsoft\visualstudio\nodejs\node.exe.  This tell me it was installed when I installed VS because I have not installed Node.